# Is it possible move mouse cursors via IR pins?

Tags: infrared, output, pins, robotics, mouse

In a mouse (with ball) there are IR sensors and phototransistor sensors (in pairs) to check the movement of the mouse in both axes.
For each axis, there is the following configuration: http://1uparcade.rmfx.com/images/kb-optics.jpg
It is possible to operate (with voltage, current and possibly frequency) externally the pin of the optical sensor to move the cursor?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes. (10 more to go)

Comment: thank you.
I need to provide the sensor with a voltage? Or it depends on the frequency? I mean, how do I determine the movement in both directions? (I tried to feed both the sensor pins with 5V and about 2kHz and the cursor moves in one direction but then I have stability problems)

Thank you!

Comment: Each sensor detects two pulses 90 degrees out of phase for direction as the ball rotates. The frequency is A LOT less than 2kHz though. Going that fast the micro in the mouse may not be able to keep up.

Comment: I did not understand how to connect the pins. I have to feed them with 5V and a particular frequency? How do I move cursor in the opposite direction? It only depends on input frequency or another?
Thanks again !!

Comment: It's easier to use a usb microcontroller with the USB HID Mouse profile. Avoid hacking the mouse and just do it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two channels on the ball driven sensor wheels. They feed out a quadrature waveform that indicates motion and direction as shown in the image below.

[image]

You can bypass the sensors by applying those signals to the appropriate point in the mouse. However, do not apply a signal that is a higher frequency than the mouse's circuitry can keep up with.

Comment: Channel A and Channel B are the two pins of IR, right?

Comment: @Papi44 There should be two IR detectors per wheel. One wheel for X the other for Y. That is, four IR detectors total.

Comment: For example, for the X axis I have this configuration: https://cdn.instructables.com/FF0/I8O3/HPZLKCQW/FF0I8O3HPZLKCQW.LARGE.jpg
On the right, the transparent device is the optical sensor with two pin or they are two optical sensors (each pin corresponds to a sensor)?
Thank you!

Comment: @Papi44 yes that is a dual sensor. The common pin is likely connected to the rail or a small resistance. The two emitters are the two phase outputs.

Comment: I meant the transparent sensor on the right (it has two pin). The one with the common pin is instead the pair of phototransistor.
So I have to feed the phototransistor pin with a certain frequency and put the common pin to ground (or power?) to move the cursor?
Thank you!

Comment: @Papi44 the one on the right is the LED.

Comment: @Papi44 it is not as simple as just feeding it a signal. You need to figure out what it needs in terms of voltages and figure out how to disable the LED while you drive the sensor.

Comment: Thank you @Trevor!

I can do several tests by increasing the voltage values. I just have to figure out how to properly connect.
I still have not figured out what I have to connect the common pin (power or ground?) and, above all, the other pin is simply supplied with a voltage (the frequency is not important?)?
I tried to connect the two pins of the LED to 5V (and 2kHz), and the cursor moves. it is wrong to work directly on the LED pins ?

Comment: @Papi44 did you not read this answer, YOu need to feed TWO square wave signals to the mouse. NOT ONE single square wave. You need to turn the LED off ! Feed the two signals to the emitters of the three pin device.

Comment: Ok, sorry @Trevor, now I understand.
However, the problem remains of how to connect the common pin (GND/Power)..

Comment: @Papi44, you need to measure what is currently there.  It will either be whatever rail voltage the mouse used or through a resistor to same. If you are feeding a signal to the emitters, you don't have to worry about  connection to the common pin, just do not feed a voltage greater than what is currently there. You do need to attach a common ground somewhere though.

Comment: @Papi44, if you can figure out the current wiring and add it to your question It would make it easier to show you what to do.

Comment: This is the mouse:
http://it.tinypic.com/r/2qw37yc/9
Here I called a,b,c the dual transistor pins and d,e the LED pins:
http://it.tinypic.com/r/n5q447/9
The dual transistor:
https://ibb.co/dXAa6F
and the LED:
https://ibb.co/jd6XmF

Thank you so much!

Comment: This is the mouse:
https://ibb.co/g2YCmF
Here I called a,b,c the dual transistor pins and d,e the LED pins:
https://ibb.co/nLipYv
The dual transistor:
https://ibb.co/dXAa6F
and the LED:
https://ibb.co/jd6XmF

Thank you so much!

[I edited links]

Comment: Trevor? You need something else? @Trevor

Comment: @Papi This is not a free design/debug service. I told you what signals you need to feed it, now go figure out the schematic of the mouse, and how to hook in your signals while turning off the LEDs.